# LEFT JOIN returns NULL if there are just one column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I try to get the latest created product price. Every Product is unique but can have different prices. However, my query only works if a product have more than a price as row in the product_price table:

[image: Table product_price]

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    i.name AS title, 
    i.id AS product_id, 
    m.name AS manufacturer, 
    image, 
    price_sales, 
    price_new, 
    price_used, 
    price_old 
FROM product_info as i 
    LEFT JOIN product_manufacturer AS m ON i.manufacturer_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM product_price ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS p ON i.id = p.id_product
WHERE category_id = 2 
    AND i.is_deactivated IS NULL 
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

I just need the latest created price row.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sbep.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the subquery:

```
(SELECT * FROM product_price ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Does not get the latest price per product, but simply the latest price, so will only ever return one row, meaning only one of your products will actually have a price.

The way to resolve this is to remove any prices where a newer one exists, so for simplicity if you look just at the price table, the following will give you only the latest product prices:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product_price AS p
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    product_price AS p2
            WHERE   p2.id_product = p.id_product
            AND     p2.created_at > p.created_at 
        );
```

However, [MySQL will optmise `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` better than `NOT EXISTS`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) (although I think the former conveys intention better), so a more efficient approach would be:

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product_price AS p
        LEFT JOIN product_price AS p2 
            ON p2.id_product = p.id_product
            AND p2.created_at > p.created_at 
WHERE   p2.id IS NULL;
```

Finally, introducing this back to your main query, you would end up with:

```
SELECT  i.name AS title, 
        i.id AS product_id, 
        m.name AS manufacturer, 
        i.image, 
        p.price_sales, 
        p.price_new, 
        p.price_used, 
        p.price_old 
FROM    product_info as i 
        LEFT JOIN product_manufacturer AS m 
            ON m.id = i.manufacturer_id
        LEFT JOIN product_price AS p 
            ON p.id_product = i.id
        LEFT JOIN product_price AS p2 
            ON p2.id_product = p.id_product
            AND p2.created_at > p.created_at 
WHERE   i.category_id = 2 
AND     i.is_deactivated IS NULL 
AND     p2.id IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 20;
```